# Creating and deleting an AWS EC2 instance from shell

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was wondering if I could use a shell script on a remote server to create an amazon EC2 instance from an existing saved snapshot, and also delete that instance too.

I was sure it was possible, but I havent been able to run any example code to do it so im starting to doubt it now.

So, can anyone tell me how this is done please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a quite detailed description on the Amazon webpage how to do this:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/Welcome.html

At which point are you struggling?

Comment: Because on this page, there doesnt seem to be a command to start an instance from another remote server via shell http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/command-reference.html

Comment: ec2-start-instances -> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-StartInstances.html